# Android Realm for-loop - RealmResults are removed during looping

Tags: android, realm

I have some code running in an IntentService, doing image uploads.  It starts by fetching posts that are "queued" for upload, then it loops through those and makes synchronous Retrofit calls to upload images.  Fairly straight-forward.  See code for reference:

```
final RealmResults<Post> posts = realm.where(Post.class)
            .equalTo("uniqueCode", uniqueCode)
            .equalTo("queued", true)
            .isEmpty("url")
            .findAll();

Log.d(TAG, "post count: " + posts.size());

if (posts != null && posts.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "posts count now: " + posts.size());

        Post post = posts.get(i);

        Post submittedPost = api.uploadPhoto(<params>); // Retrofit call, which works fine

        if (submittedPost != null) {
            realm.beginTransaction();
            post.setQueued(false);
            post.setUrl(submittedPost.getUrl());
            realm.commitTransaction();

            sendBroadcastUpdate(); // This updates the UI in places
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, each time it goes through the for-loop, the size of the results ("posts" in my case above) goes down by one - this is confirmed by my Log output that decrements by one each time, so it only gets through a few of the results.  It's almost as if each time I'm committing the Realm transaction during the looping, it's updating my fetched query results, even though that array is set to be final.

I confirmed that it doesn't do this if I don't set those values ('queued' and 'url').  Which tells me it's updating the results somehow.  I've tried different things, such as a while-loop (i.e. "while (posts.size() > 0)"), but it gets through 2-3 of them, and then all of a sudden the size of "posts" is immediately 0, for no reason at all that I can see.

I've also tried doing the begin/commit before and after the loop, but it yields similar results.  Same goes for if I convert it to an array before processing.  It seems that it always gets through a few of them, and then the size is automatically set to 0, so it exits the loop.

This strikes me as very bizarre, especially since I set the results to be "final" - is this expected behavior?  Does anyone know a way around this, by chance?

For reference, we are using Realm version: 0.86.

Comment: `even though that array is set to be final.` setting a variable to `final` means you can't modify the reference, but it doesn't mean the item you assign suddenly becomes immutable. In fact, that is what this article was about http://blog.danlew.net/2017/05/30/mutable-vals-in-kotlin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Realm versions where version < 0.89.0 or version >= 3.0.0*, this is expected behavior (see [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#iterations--snapshots)).

`RealmResults` is a view to the latest version of the database (for a given object type where given conditions are met), and a transaction is essentially "creating the latest version of the database" meaning the `RealmResults` starts to see the new modified data with each modification.

See following:

```
final RealmResults<Post> posts = realm.where(Post.class)
        .equalTo("uniqueCode", uniqueCode)
        .equalTo("queued", true) // <---- condition true
        .isEmpty("url")
        .findAll();


...

    if (submittedPost != null) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        post.setQueued(false); // <---- condition false
        post.setUrl(submittedPost.getUrl());
        realm.commitTransaction();

        sendBroadcastUpdate(); // This updates the UI in places
    }
```

As you create a transaction, you start to see the latest version, in which case the `RealmResults` will no longer contain elements that have `queued == false`.

For Realm 0.88.3 or older, you need to iterate the RealmResults in reverse, or "iterate while the results isn't empty" (I used this method a lot before the 0.89.0 breaking change killed it, but it'd work with 3.0.0+ again so that's nice)

```
realm.refresh(); // enforce the next RealmResults to be *definitely* up-to-date

final RealmResults<Post> posts = realm.where(Post.class)
            .equalTo("uniqueCode", uniqueCode)
            .equalTo("queued", true)
            .isEmpty("url")
            .findAll();

while(!posts.isEmpty()) {
    Post post = posts.get(0);
    Post submittedPost = api.uploadPhoto(<params>); // Retrofit call, which works fine
    if (submittedPost != null) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        post.setQueued(false);
        post.setUrl(submittedPost.getUrl());
        realm.commitTransaction();
        sendBroadcastUpdate(); // This updates the UI in places
    }
}
```

For Realm 3.0.0+, you can either use `for(Post post : results) {` (iterators), or [you can use a collection snapshot](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#iterations--snapshots) directly.

```
final RealmResults<Post> results = realm.where(Post.class)
    .equalTo("uniqueCode", uniqueCode)
    .equalTo("queued", true) // 
    .isEmpty("url")
    .findAll();
final OrderedRealmCollection<Post> posts = results.createSnapshot(); // <-- snapshot

for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) { 
   //...
```

---

*(and honestly, the behavior in-between was a hack, where the RealmResults was not synchronized to see the latest version, and 3.0.0 had to undo this hack)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, and it makes sense now.  However, I changed my for-loop to iterate in reverse, i.e. "for (int i = posts.size()-1; i > 0; i--)", but I still run into the same issue.  It gets through two of them, and then it crashed when the results size jumped to 0.  That just doesn't seem right to me, unless I'm still doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Forgot to mention that we are using Realm version: 0.86.  I can try to upgrade to the latest, but I worry it may break a lot of stuff, as this app is pretty heavily reliable on Realm.

Comment: Technically you'd be skipping index 0 because it should be `i >= 0`, but it should **not** crash. I was actually expecting that this was the result of a 2.3.0 => 3.x upgrade, didn't *actually* expect to see an old version, heh

Comment: I've added a 0.86.0 compatible answer. Upgrading to 2.x+ will break your `sendBroadcastUpdate();` method, because Realm updating UI thread via handler notification order is no longer guaranteed, only RealmChangeListeners are. Realm 0.88.3 is pretty nice though.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!!  Weird, because I had attempted this exact solution yesterday, but instead of using isEmpty(), I had ".size() > 0".  It didn't work with the latter for some reason, but with isEmpty, it works great.  Thank you again!!

Comment: If you added `realm.refresh()` (as the answer specifies) and that fixed it, then you might have an unclosed Realm instance on the thread which made you obtain an out-of-date `RealmResults` from which you obtained a wrong `size()` value.

Comment: Ahh, I bet that's it!  I did indeed add in realm.refresh() with the latest change, and it worked fine after that.  I'll check around the code to see if there may be an unclosed Realm instance.  Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior of an Iterator. Once you call .next(), you get the item and it is removed from the iterator. If you want to keep items, write a utility to convert an iterator to an ArrayList or some similar thing. You can read more about iterators here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Comment: I actually shouldn't have used the term "Iterator", as it's a for-loop that I'm using (not an explicit java Iterator).  I am forced to use for-loops with Realm, as anything else will cause a crash, including an Iterator.  Sorry for the confusion there; I've updated my question title to be more specific.  But anyway - my question still applies; I am a bit stumped why the original fetched results are being modified during my for-loop?

Comment: Have you tried beginning a realm transaction before the loop and committing it after the loop? You will not be opening/closing the db connection too many times then.
Also, I have never experienced a for-each loop problem with realm. Maybe try that one?

Comment: Actually did try that with the same results.  Within the for-loop it still decrements the count, and it only gets through half the results. :(

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't be able to go that route regardless, due to needing other areas of the app to make a similar fetch and update UI as the for-loop is going.